# Echo list attachment size in post

Tags: attachments, thumbnails

i have a post width 10 attachment image in post

i want querylist 10 attachment in post as:

```
<li><a href="url-img-attachment-sizefull-img1" title=""><img src="url-img-attachment-sizethumb-img1"></li>
<li><a href="url-img-attachment-sizefull-img1" title=""><img src="url-img-attachment-sizethumb-img1"></li>
.....
```

Give any code.

My code add:

```
<?php query_posts($args); if (have_posts()) { while (have_posts()) { the_post(); ?>

<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'numberposts' => 3, 'orderby' => 'rand', 'order' => 'DESC', 'post_mime_type' => 'image' ,'post_status' => null, 'post_parent' => $post->ID ); 
$attachments = get_posts($args);
    if ($attachments) {
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) { ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( $attachment->ID,'large', false ); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( $attachment->ID,'large', false ); ?>" alt="<?php echo get_post_meta($attachment->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true) ?>" /></a>
<?php }} ?>
<?php }} wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

but `<?php echo wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( $attachment->ID,'large', false ); ?>` don't show image `large` it's image : `thumbnail`

how to fix it's

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`wp_get_attachment_thumb_url()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.3.1/src/wp-includes/post.php#L0) doesn't accept three parameters. It takes one-- the attachment ID. And, as you might guess from the name of the function, it return the thumbnail URL `*_thumb_url`. If you'd have simply checked the Codex entry for the function you'd have seen that.

If you'd check the Codex, you'd see several other things too

1. Don't use [`query_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)

   > Note: This function isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes.
2. `numberposts` has long since been deprecated. In fact, it may not
   work at all anymore as I can't find it mentioned in the Codex any
   longer, nor do I see it the source for `WP_Query`.

Let's correct this. The key function you want is [`wp_get_attachment_image_src()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src), but your code is an poorly formatted, unreadable mess. Let's fix that too.

1. Use a new `WP_Query` object instead of `query_posts()` I don't know
   what arguments you are using as you didn't post that part.
2. Use `posts_per_page` instead of `numberposts` (which name never made
   sense anyway)
3. Use `wp_get_attachment_image_src()`
4. Indent, and format, and organize. Save your sanity man!

Which gives us...

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'post'); // not sure what your actually are.
$images = new WP_Query($args);

if ($images->have_posts()) { 
  while ($images->have_posts()) { 
    $images->the_post();
    $args = array( 
      'post_type' => 'attachment', 
      'posts_per_page' => 3, 
      'orderby' => 'rand', 
      'order' => 'DESC', 
      'post_mime_type' => 'image' ,
      'post_status' => null, 
      'post_parent' => $post->ID 
    ); 
    $attachments = get_posts($args);
    if ($attachments) {
      foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) { 
        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID,'large', false ); 
        if (empty($image[0])) continue;
        $image_meta = get_post_meta($attachment->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true); ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
          <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image_meta ?>" />
        </a><?php
      }
    }
  }
} 
wp_reset_postdata();
```